# Can I force the amsalpha bibliography style to sort papers by the same authors chronologically?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

> Can I force the amsalpha bibliography style to sort papers by the same
>   authors chronologically?

I am using amsrefs package with the alphabetic option, which gives each reference a label such as [GLS07], or [Hap88]. Essentially the rule is that for single author papers, the label will consist of the first three letters of the surname, plus the last two digits of the year, and for papers with multiple authors the label will be the complete list of last initials, plus the last two digits of the year.

The amsrefs package overrules the \bibliographystle command, so this is omitted; the package is being run with the options abbrev, alphabetic and msc-links (alphabetic being the option that produces the alpha-style labels).

In the output, the references are sorted alphabetically by label. There is [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13944/sort-by-author-in-alpha-bibliography) asking how to force the bibliography to be sorted alphabetically by author - I agree that this is not a good thing to do, as it will make it potentially harder for the reader to find the right reference, particularly if there are lots of them. However, sorting purely alphabetically by label puts, for example, [FZ00] before [FZ99]. To me this seems confusing - I understand that the 00 refers to the year 2000 and 99 to 1999, so [FZ99] should come before [FZ00]. Can I change this, ideally without having to manually specify the entire order of the bibliography?

(I guess there is a small additional question - do most people agree that you would look for [FZ00] after [FZ99]? If it's just me, I should probably leave it alone. I suppose there's an argument to be made that just as the reader doesn't necessarily know what the initials are for in order to search alphabetically by author in the list of references, they also don't know whether 00 is 1900 or 2000; but I think in this case it's easier to guess.)

**Update:** If I don't use amsrefs, and instead specify the style using \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}, then the problem goes away. But then I don't know how to use the abbrev and msc-links options, which I still want. It does seem that there should be a way to get this to work through amsrefs.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [FZ00] will come later than [FZ99]. About sorting by author and not by label, I disagree.

Comment: That's interesting - I picked that example from an actual document that I've compiled. (It also puts [Lus91] after [Lus00]). I'm not sure of the best way to provide a minimal example of my code in this situation is, but I will try to come up with something.

Comment: I don't really want to get into a discussion about sorting by author - AMS's own style guide insists that the sorting is by label, and I don't disagree with them, although I appreciate that some people do.

Comment: In my experiment, if the year in the [FZ00] reference is 1900, it will come before [FZ99] (with year 1999); if the year is 2000, it will come later.

Comment: That's extremely strange, and suggests I've somehow modified the default behaviour. I added a sentence to the question to explain how the bibliography is implemented - I've stopped short of including extracts from the .bib file because I don't think they'll be useful, but I can include them if you like.

Comment: Ah - it appears that the behaviour is different depending on whether you use \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}, or specify the style through an option on the amsrefs package (which ignores any \bibliographystyle command).

Comment: From `amsref` documentation: “No sorting of the bibliography items is done. The entries will appear in your document in the same order that they appeared in the database files.”

Comment: using bibtex, `\noop{xxx}` to add something to a title to affect the sort order is described nicely in this answer: [How to force a certain sorting of two .bib entries?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160195/579).

Comment: @egreg Now I am even more confused - I have also found this sentence in the documentation, but it doesn't describe the behaviour that actually occurs. I have a lot of references by the same authors (all 21st century!) which are alphabetical by title in the .bib file, but appear chronologically in the bibliography. I guess this is either part of the abbreviation option, or in the amsart document style - I will experiment more.

Comment: @barbara Thanks; that is a neat trick, but I'd prefer to do it automatically if possible. At the moment, my favourite solution would be to use \bibliographystyle rather than amsrefs, and work out how to produce the effect of the abbrev and msc-links options that way.

Comment: @MattPressland -- a comment on another question suggests using, e.g., `year={1970a}` and `year={1970b}` in the `.bib` file, but i don't know how that would come out in the bibliography itself (not tested).  that question is [Natbib+harvard.bst: papers in same year listed in the wrong order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78027/579).  (i'd really like to know a better way myself, to be able to answer questions that come up in ams production.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton In this case, the .bib file has "year={1999}" and "year={2000}", so the alphabetical order agrees with the chronological order - unfortunately the issue is only introduced once the labels are produced and then sorted.

Comment: @egreg I looked at the documentation again - the sentence you quote refers to using a .ltb file instead of using BibTEX. Section 2.3 says, on using BibTEX instead, "you can take advantage of BibTEX’s ability to sort your items for you". The issue seems to be that amsrfs with the alphabetical option does not pass the same sorting instructions to BibTEX as using \bibliographystyle{amsalpha} instead of amsrfs. (There are also some small formatting differences). It doesn't make a difference to use the default article document style rather than amsart.

Comment: @MattPressland -- i think the logical approach in this case may be to extend the keys to use the full 4-year date.  the way the keys are assigned is suboptimal, so some manual approach is needed.  by the way, i've now gone back and looked at the manual (`texdoc bibtex), and on p.4, item 6, the `\noop{...}` technique is described along with some additional possibilities i hadn't thought of and hadn't seen mentioned here.  i've also read your answer, and think that modifying the `year` field in the `.bib` file as suggested in the manual is, in the long run, the cleanest approach.

Comment: one final comment: if you are using only `amsrefs`, according to the manual (p.4), "No sorting of the bibliography items is done. The entries will appear in your document in the same order that they appeared in the database files."

Comment: @barbara I can attest that using {\noop\} in the year field does force the behaviour I want - if you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it. This does seem like the cleanest solution, although I'm still a little uneasy that it might cause strange behaviour if I switch style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the canonical order of bibtex sort fields is the following: author(s)
(or sort keys if an `alpha` sort is requested), year, title.

whether the bibtex ordering is controlled by a `plain` or an `alpha`
`.bst` file, if the year of publication is the same, the element
that will control the sort is the title.  so if the title of the
earlier part begins with "z", only special handling can force that
to sort before an item with a title starting with "a".  if the year
of publication is different, and the second part was published in a
year earlier than the first, the same problem holds.

let's take an extreme case.  part "a" was published in 2000 and
part "b" in 1999.  this will result in sort keys (if an `alpha` style
is used) for which the two-digit years sort the entries "out of order".
even fiddling with how the title is sorted won't help here.
the most direct approach is to adjust the year field in a way that
won't affect the output except for the order of the entries.

the fact that multiple works by the same author(s) don't necessarily
sort in logical order was recognized by the author of bibtex ,
who provided this workaround in the manual (`texdoc bibtex`) on page 4.

in the `.bib` database, add this command:

```
@PREAMBLE{ "\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }
```

this will be passed along to the `.bbl` file, from which it will
be applied in the latex run.

in the affected item entries in the `.bib` file, modify the `date`
fields to do your dirty work:

```
year = "{\noopsort{1999b}}1999"
 ...
year = "{\noopsort{1999a}}2000"
```

of course, the artificial sort field should be chosen so that these
entries (according to the manual)

> come out in a reasonable spot relative to the author's other works.

although the `\noopsort` technique could be applied to the title,
always using the date should not have any untoward effect in future
processing; only if additional books by the same author are added
to the `.bib` file would it even have to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a workaround solution that is fairly bad, but not as bad (to me) as modifying the .bib file somehow.

> Load `amsrefs` with the option `y2k`, and run BibTeX (the option `alphabetic` should also be used). Then remove the `y2k` option before running LaTeX.

The reason this works is that amsrefs runs BibTeX using the biblipgraphy style [amsxprt](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsxport.pdf), which is a container for several styles - which style is selected depends on the options that are specified when loading `amsrefs`. When you run BibTeX, a .bbl file is output with the references in an order compatible with the alphabetical ordering of the labels that `amsrefs` will create. The labels that would be created using `alphabetic` and `y2k` include the full year, so sorting these labels alphabetically is equivalent to the sorting I want. If you then remove the `y2k` option again before running LaTeX, the shorter labels with only two digits of the year are created, but the references still appear in the order they appear in the .bbl file, so I get the sorting I wanted.

I would be interested to know if there is a way to tell `amsrefs` to use the style in `amsxprt` corresponding to choosing the options `alphabetic` and `y2k` (which is called `amsry` apparently), without having to actually select these options.

The design of `amsrefs` seems to make it fairly clear that the ordering I want to use is not the same as the ordering AMS want to use - except that if I use the bibliography style `amsalpha` (without `amsrefs`), I get the same labels but with my preferred sorting.

Comment: i think you mean `amsrefs`, not `amsrfs`.  and please do look into the modification (in the `.bib` file) of the `year` field; that should fix the ordering once and for all, and allow you to reuse the `.bib` file for other projects.  since it's recommended in the manual, it shouldn't be considered "cheating".

Comment: I did, thanks! I will have a look in the manual - cheating was too strong, but I'd rather not change too much in the .bib file in case I change style later and get strange behaviour.